# When accessing PDF on iPhone over local network gives grey screen

Tags: ios, pdf, web-applications

When i try accessing certain PDF's on iPhone over local network it gives grey screen. I have been accessing it via my internal ip at port 8888 eg. 10.0.0.14:8888. The weird thing is, that the files aren't seemingly damaged because I can view all of them on my mac at localhost:8888, 127.0.0.1:8888, and 10.0.0.14:8888.

And to add to it, it opens one of the pdf's but none of the others, so its possible that the problem it particular to just those files that don't open.

Thanks

Comment: Post the relevant code giving you an issue.

Comment: Thats the thing, it isn't a code problem because all it is, is a page with links on it to pdf's, a simple webpage with links. Its when I open them on my iPhone 4s and iPad 3 when it doesn't work. I tried it on the iOS Simulator and it works as it should. @rmaddy

Comment: In other words you are browsing a webpage with Safari and clicking on a PDF link in Safari is showing the gray in Safari. Is that what is happening?

Comment: Yes thats exactly it. Except one of the pdf's shows it perfectly as it should and the others just show a grey screen with the open in iBooks bar

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is creating the grey screen is restrictions on web pages. It must stop some pdf's from opening